# git clean -f -d removed files from my local directory

Tags: git, git-clean

git clean -f -d removed files from my local directory as well How do I retreive them?
I used it to remove untracked directories and files and found that it also deleted it from my local file system. Is this possible? What did i do wrong and is there a way to retreive them?

Comment: "What did I do wrong?" This depends on what you expected to happen. It sounds like `git clean -f -d` behaved as documented: it deleted untracked files and directories from your working copy. By definition, if they're untracked they're not in the repository, so there's nowhere else they could have been deleted from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a previous answer says, if you're working on Linux, you can't retrieve them.  They're gone: that's the point of "git clean".  Unless you're using a filesystem capable on doing snapshots but then, you would probably know how to get them back.

If your goal was to avoid seeing them in "git status", you have two possibilities:

**A)**

```
git status -uno
```

does not print untracked files and directories.

**B)**
If there are a fixed set of files (or a filename pattern) that you will never want to see in "git status" nor put them under versioning, you can "ignore" them.  You simply have to put their name or pattern in a file named ".gitignore" at your repository's root.

This is typically used for generated files.

The following example ignores filenames ending with ".html" and the file called "out/myFile.txt":

```
*.html
out/myFile.txt
```

See

```
git help ignore
```

for more info.

Comment: yes working on Linux. So I guess its gone :-( price one pays for being a newbie in git.

Comment: They say there are 2 kind of people: the ones that have lost work due to a wrong git command and the ones that haven't lost work **yet** :)

Comment: note that all hope is not always lost: if the files are opened in an editor and if said editor hasn't automatically reloaded them, you can save them again.

Answer (score 1):

The files deleted by `git clean` were untracked, which means git didn't keep an extra copy of them. If you need to retrieve them, your best bet is to *immediately* remount the filesystem read-only, and run whatever deleted file recovery tool is appropriate for your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends upon how you deleted them.  In Windows these files should have just gone to the recycle bin.  In Linux I believe git is using the rm command so you should do a quick search on how to recover files accidentally deleted with rm.